# How to use multiple true statements in If condition?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script

The last If statement doesn't work when executed. The code has to be executed again for it to work. So is it possible to use multiple true statements in a IF condition?

```
function sort(){

  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var cell0 = SS.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B4:K4");
  var cell1 = SS.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B5:K5");
  var cell2 = SS.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B6:K6");
  var cell3 = SS.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B7:K7");
  var cell4 = SS.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B8:K8");


  var lecc0 = SS.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("L4");
  var lecc1 = SS.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("L5");
  var lecc2 = SS.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("L6");
  var lecc3 = SS.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("L7");
  var lecc4 = SS.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("L8");

  var cl = SS.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B4");
  var cl1 = SS.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B5");


  var clv = cl.getValue();
  var cl1v = cl1.getValue();

  if((cl.isBlank()) && cl1 !== ""){cell1.copyTo(cell0)}; 
  if(clv == cl1v){cell1.clearContent()} else {};

}
```

Comment: The most likely reason that the second if does not execute is because clv does not equal clv1

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Did my answer help with your problem? If yes, please make it the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last if is being executed (otherwise your program would be throwing some kind of error / exception and stopping the execution), it's simply hitting the else statement (which does nothing).

```
if(clv == cl1v) {
   cell1.clearContent() //it will only execute when the if condition returns true
} 
else {
   //this is being executed in the first run
};
```

I don't recommend writing inline code like that. It's way harder to spot problems.

> So is it possible to use multiple true statements in a IF condition?

Yes, there is no problem. You can validate more than one condition by using logical operators like AND, OR, etc.

```
if(condition1 && condition2 || condition3) 
{ 
   //code goes here
}
```